# how to get bundle identifier of Safari.app by mac os x apis

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, safari

I want to launch some webpages specifically in safari web-browser. I am using [`openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:) to do so. This requires app id. For safari it is `com.apple.safari`. It works as expected.

Is there any better way to get `com.apple.safari` by api calls ?

Note: I am ignoring default web-browser and opening it in safari.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think this is the only way to do it. If there was some api call to get this app id, probably, it required some another identifier as input argument. And now there's at least one identifier you should keep in memory.

Just define a constant and use it

```
#define kSafariAppId @"com.apple.safari"
```

Comment: Thanks. I am doing similar. `NSString* const kSafariID = @"com.apple.safari";` This would be in line with type checking